# How do I grep for a string that occurs before the error code when the number of lines prior to error code is not consistent

Tags: grep

When I find an error string in a log file, I need to know what caused
the error.  But the filename that failed is a random number of lines
prior to the error string.  Example:

logfile:

```
This **specific backup.tar** failed\n 
Because of this\n
Or because of this\n
Then some random lines of output\n  
Exiting -- searched-for string appears\n
```

If I used 'grep Exiting --before-context=4', I would find that **backup.tar** failed.  But the number of random lines varies.

So I would like to use --before-context="string", or in this case --before-context="*.tar*".

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) instead of `grep` ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `grep` isn't up to this job. Try something like this in `awk`:

```
$ cat foo.txt
This specific backup.tar failed
Because of this
Or because of this
Then some random lines of output
Exiting -- searched-for string appears
$ awk '/This specific .* failed/ { filename = $3 } /searched-for string/ { print filename }' foo.txt
backup.tar
```

Comment: Almost. I know the name of the file the error might be in.  If it does exist within that log file, then look backward to find which backup failed.  Maybe :   grep 'Exiting' logfile, if exists, then search for '/failed/' within the log file.  Thanks for the suggestion tho!